# Why did this edit get rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing

My [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/476829). Note that hg8 said

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

So he edits it himself. He did the same as I did but... He changed an `h` to `H`...

Shouldn't my edit have been accepted?

Comment: Well, it didn't fix all of the issues which the other edit did fix, anyway, what does it matter whose edit got accepted?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  True - I just thought it was rather ridiculous

Comment: I don't think that it really even matters whose edit is shown to be accepted, surely you are doing it to improve the post, and not just for rep or for it to say that you edited it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda well obviously... I mean c'mon - 2 rep?

Comment: Hi @DevRobot. My bad I mistaken. Your edit should not have been rejected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should have. However, it is very easy to click on the wrong button and choose "Reject and edit" instead of "Improve edit":

[image]

That's <del>probably</del> [what happened](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14511/why-did-this-edit-get-rejected/14512?noredirect=1#comment25507_14512), don't worry about it.

Comment: I meant improve edit indeed. (because I just changed @DevRobot html code to markdown format.)

Comment: Oh right - @hg8 So I should ideally be using markdown format?

Comment: @Dev it is preferred, yes. It makes editing easier and standardizes the formatting.

Comment: @DevRobot: you're a robot!  hg8 is only human...  Humans make mistakes! (like pushing the wrong buttons) **:D**

Comment: @Fabby Lol - Good point, I aught to remember that

Answer (score 2):

You formatted the error message as code using the `<pre>` HTML tag,
he formatted it as blockquote using the Markdown `>` syntax and corrected a capitalization mistake.

Whether this error message should now have been formatted as code or quote is in this case pretty unimportant and would be another discussion. I would consider both options equal.

However, it's strongly recommended to prefer Markdown syntax over HTML tags wherever possible, so also to format the line as code, you should indent it with 4 spaces (Markdown syntax), which will then internally be converted and displayed on the site using the HTML tags `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.

He however did not only do this minor formatting improvement, but another necessary spelling/grammar correction as well.

---

After having summarized the difference between those two edits, we can conclude that the second edit is indeed better and follows the formatting guidelines, but in my opinion it is not too different from yours, especially as your intention was not wrong, so i would not have rejected and replaced the first edit, but improved it.

As he said in the comments to terdon's other answer, it was an accident and he wanted to click the "Improve edit" button instead of "Reject and edit". So except that you now learned how to better format posts, you should not worry about this. :-)

Comment: Right thanks - I won't worry about it **:-)**